# asp.net webapi UseOAuthBearerAuthentication vs UseJwtBearerAuthentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, oauth, jwt

can anybody explain me what is the difference between UseOAuthBearerAuthentication and UseJwtBearerAuthentication?

Why should i use 'UseOAuthBearerAuthentication' over 'UseJwtBearerAuthentication' or vice versa?

How can i decide which option will be the best for my system?

Thanks,
Szymo

Answer (score 19):

UseJwtBearerAuthentication middleware is used when the token is created by an external OAuth2 authorization servers like Identityserver, Auth0. This is a standard token format.

UseOAuthBearerAuthentication middleware is used when the token is created by Katana OAuth2 authorization server. This authorization server uses a proprietary token format.

UseJwtBearerAuthentication middleware is a good option out the two. This middleware uses the token format (JWT) specified in OpenId Connect spec.All the external authorization servers use this token format.

Thank you,
Soma.

Comment: it is the answer.